Move button text down and change button color
In WordPress, I was able to change some radio buttons to look like buttons using the below CSS:
.gfield_radio {
   list-style-type:none;
   margin:25px 0 0 0;
   padding:0;
}
.gfield_radio li {
  float:left;
  margin:0 5px 0 0;
  width:250px;
  height:60px;
  position:relative;
}
.gfield_radio label, .gfield_radio input {
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
}
.gfield_radio input[type="radio"] {
  opacity:0.011;
  z-index:100;
}
.gfield_radio input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  background: #248f24;
}
.gfield_radio label {
  padding:5px;
  border:1px solid #CCC; 
  cursor:pointer;
  z-index:90;
  color: white;
  background: #5cd65c;
  text-align: center;
}
.gfield_radio label:hover {
  background: #248f24;
}

Here is how the radio buttons look now:

What I am trying to do now is make the second button red and push the text down to the middle, which I seem to be having a problem doing.
Using the inspector, I can see the radio buttons:

My attempt to change the button color looks like this:
.gfield_radio #choice_6265_6_0 {
  background: red;
}

My attempt to push the button text down looks like this:
.gfield_radio label {
   padding:5px;
   border:1px solid #CCC; 
   cursor:pointer;
   z-index:90;
   color: white;
   background: #5cd65c;
   text-align: center;
   vertical-align: center; // <-- trying to center the text in the middle of the button
}

Neither of the above works. Both buttons are still green, and the text remains near the top-middle.
How can I fix this to make it work?
** EDIT **
Here is the actual code from the inspector:
<div class='ginput_container ginput_container_radio'><ul class='gfield_radio' id='input_6265_6'>
<li class='gchoice gchoice_6265_6_0'>
<input name='input_6' type='radio' value='gpoll6cf289289'  id='choice_6265_6_0' tabindex='1'   />
<label for='choice_6265_6_0' id='label_6265_6_0'>YES</label>
</li>
<li class='gchoice gchoice_6265_6_1'>
<input name='input_6' type='radio' value='gpoll66198d639'  id='choice_6265_6_1' tabindex='2'   />
<label for='choice_6265_6_1' id='label_6265_6_1'>NO</label>
</li></ul></div>


Could you copy code from inspector and paste it instead of the screenshot?

@gael - I just added the actual code.

The id you are targeting #choice_6265_6_0 is on the input field while the background color is on the label. You need to target .gfield_radio label#label_6265_6_0 for the red background. For the vertical align you can delete the line and replace it with a line-height: 40px;. Perhaps will you have to adjust pixels according to your global styles.

@gael - your suggestion worked for me.  If you post an answer, I'll accept it.  Thank you.

@gael - and I've already started using ChatGPT to help me here and there.  Thank you.
